# How to initialize NamedParameterJdbcTemplate variable

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

My code looks like this:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate stmt;
String sql = "INSERT INTO ....."; // <- some insert statement
Map<String, Object> named = ...;
...
stmt.update(sql, named);
```

But when I try to compile my program, I'm getting this error message:

> variable stmt might not have been initialized
>
> stmt.update(sql, named);
>
> ^
>
> 1 error

In all examples (like this [one](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-in.html#.VjYnVytvDig)), that I've seen NamedParameterJdbcTemplate variable was not initialized at all. So, I wonder what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: "NamedParameterJdbcTemplate variable was not initialized at all". Read the tutorial you linked to again, it _is_ initialized. With the `@Autowire` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, the life cycle of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is managed by [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/).

If you are not using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` in a Spring Context, you can create a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` from a `DataSource` or a `JdbcTemplate`.

Here's the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html)